# Moving `Selection` to the right position, when text shifts as a result of clicking into the Editor

Tags: lexicaljs

I have an editor which hides specific text ocurences whenever it is blurred - all text matched by a regexp is moved (via [registerNodeTransform](https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/transforms)) under a special node `HidingNode`, where `HidingNode extends TextNode`. All instances of `HidingNode` get `display: none` whenever Editor is not focused.

This means that whenever I click into the input, all instances of `HidingNode` suddenly appear, and shift the rest of the text. Following the click, `Selection` moves to whichever node happens to be under the cursor **after** all `HidingNode`s appear. I would love to change this, so that `Selection` moves to whichever node (and offset) was under the cursor **before** the click registered (aka the node user was actually hovering over when he made the click).

I tried to measure the position of `Selection` in many ways, in hopes of capturing it before `HidingNode`s appear, but I was only able to get the final position, where `HidingNodes` are already visible.

I tried to manually compensate for the shift the following way:

```js
editor.update(() => {
  const allTextNodes = $getRoot().getAllTextNodes()
  const totalCaretPosition = $getCaretPositionInNodeList(allTextNodes)
  if (totalCaretPosition === null) return

  const nonHidingNodes = allTextNodes.filter(node => !$isHidingNode(node))
  $moveCaretToNthPositionInNodeList(nonHidingNodes, totalCaretPosition)
})
```

And this works as intended, but **only with monospace fonts** - otherwise the number of appearing `HidingNode` characters rarely matches the number of characters displaced by them.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to, or am I out of luck?

I'm using `@lexical/react`.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround. I don't really like it, but it gets the job done for now.

Inside my `ContentEditable` component, instead of

```js
const isFocused = !useIsFocused()

return <StyledDiv $hideHiddenNodes={!isFocused} /* ... */ />
```

I do

```js
const isFocused = useIsFocused()
const [isFocusedDelayed, setIsFocusedDelayed] = useState(isFocused)

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => setIsFocusedDelayed(isFocused), 0)
}, [isFocused])

return <StyledDiv $hideHiddenNodes={!isFocusedDelayed} /* ... */ />
```

which seems to give Editor just enough space to determine focus before hidden nodes appear.

I'm still looking for a propper answer, since this doesn't seem very reliable.